Analogue of EV3 gyroscope for Arduino or precise rotations in space
For a long time I worked with the Lego Mindstorm EV3 set. There I made precise turns in space using a gyroscopic sensor. Recently I switched to Arduino Nano.
I have a GY-521 gyroscope sensor with accelerometer on the MPU 6050 board.
I heard that it can be used to navigate in space. But I did not find a good example of how to make precise turns, say, by 90 degrees.
